# Devise authentication responds sometimes with 302 instead of 201

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, http-response-codes

I have modified Devise's session controller slightly to make it respond with 201 code even if an user is logged in:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    resource[:is_admin] = resource.is_admin?
    #respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    render :status => :created, :location => '/#/editor', :json => resource
  end
end
```

(the last line replaces the commented one), but it keeps responding to authentication JSON with 302 status code instead of 201. What am I doing wrong?